# Watch observer's unsubscription from an observable (System.Reactive)

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I want to be notified (Eg. hit breakpoint) when a subscription to my observable is disposed.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this extension method:

```
public static IObservable<T> OnUnsubscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action unsubscribe) =>
    Observable
        .Create<T>(o =>
            new CompositeDisposable(
                source.Subscribe(o),
                Disposable.Create(unsubscribe)));
```

Try it like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    IDisposable subscription =
        Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
            .OnUnsubscribe(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("/* break-point here */");
            })
            .Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
            
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
    
    subscription.Dispose();
}
```

That produces:

```
0
1
/* break-point here */
```

Please note that this also fires when the observable ends naturally.

Comment: *"Please note that this also fires when the observable ends naturally."* -- So how it differs from the `Finally` operator?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Hmmmm. Good point. I wrote `OnUnsubscribe` because `Finally` didn't fire on disposal of the subscription, but I just tested it and now it does. That's disturbing. Has the functionality changed?

Comment: I think that the `Finally` had always the same behavior. It is invoked when the sequence is unsubscribed, either forcefully or as a result of the termination of the sequence.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I'm a bit surprised about that. I do remember that there was a reason I created this operator. In any case, it's not hard to fix. I'll have a go later, but it might be a few weeks as I'm on holiday and won't have much time until November.